# LaTeX beamer handout mode textpos

Tags: beamer, textpos

I'm using `beamer` with `textpos` to place certain blocks at particular positions (in particular, I use the `textblock*` environment).

When I attempt to create a handout, the pieces of text within `textblock*` are moved into (what seems to me) random positions of the page.

Any advice?

Here is a small example:

```
\documentclass[t, handout]{beamer}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[letterpaper, border shrink = 5mm, landscape]

\mode<presentation>{
  \setbeamercovered{invisible}
}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\title{Presentation Title}

\author{
  A, B
}

\institute[Institute]{
  The Institute
}

\date{September 5, 2012}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Some title}
  Some text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[center]{Part A}
  \begin{textblock*}{300pt}(0.1\textwidth, 0.5\textheight)
    \Large
    \centering
    This title should not appear at the first slide!
  \end{textblock*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Wouldn't just removing the `absolute` package option solve your problem?

```
\documentclass[t,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage[overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[letterpaper, border shrink = 5mm, landscape]

\mode<presentation>{
  \setbeamercovered{invisible}
}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}

\title{Presentation Title}

\author{
  A, B
}

\institute[Institute]{
  The Institute
}

\date{September 5, 2012}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Some title}
  Some text
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[center]{Part A}
  \begin{textblock*}{300pt}(0.1\textwidth, 0.5\textheight)
    \Large
    \centering
    This title should not appear at the first slide!
  \end{textblock*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It sort of does. The slides in the handout are not identical to the actual handouts, but that is solvable.

Thank you!

Comment: @user1451817 don't forget to upvote Gonzalo's answer using the up arrow. If he has solved the problem, please consider accepting it using the green check mark. This helps keep the site tidy, and also helps to keep Gonzalo at the top of reputation charts :)

Answer (score 2):

Removing the `absolute` should indeed help.  This is noted in passing in the textpos manual, in the section on 'Interactions'

> This is because Textpos in absolute mode places its text onto the page at the last moment before the page is shipped out, which will be after Prosper has rotated the page from portrait to landscape format, so that the {textblock} contents end up at the correct position on the portrait page, but the wrong position on the landscape page [...] The same appears to be true with the beamer package.

This will solve the problem as long as the `textblock` is the first thing on the slide.  If it doesn't solve the problem, can you post an example of it failing and I can take a look at that.