# Change in the header for the handout

Tags: beamer, textpos, pgfpages

I am running into a weird problem. When I run my code in beamer mode, the logo that I use in each slide (in the right top corner) stays there and does not move. When I try to make handouts, the logo changes its position and goes to a weird place. Any thought? Help? Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass [11 pt, xcolor=pdftex,x11names,table]{beamer} 
%\documentclass[11 pt, handout,xcolor=pdftex,x11names,table]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgf, pgfpages, pgfplots}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Madrid}
    \usecolortheme{orchid}
    \usecolortheme{whale}
}
\title[]{Hi}
\author {\Large{\emph{Me}}}
\date[\today]{\today \\ $ $ \\
\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{logo.eps}}
\makeatletter
\def\strokeifnotempty{%
\expandafter\ifvoid\csname pgfpages@box@\the\pgf@cpn\endcsname
\let\@next=\relax
\else
\let\@next=\pgfstroke
\fi
\@next%
}
\makeatother
\mode<handout>
{
  \usepackage{pgf}
  \usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{2 on 1 boxed}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperheight} 
  \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperwidth}
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{10pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=2,%
    physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight,%
    physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}
  {%
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\strokeifnotempty,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=0.85\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{0.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.25\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {%
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\strokeifnotempty,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=0.85\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.75\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  }
\IfFileExists{\jobname.aux}{
  \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1 boxed}[letterpaper, border shrink=5mm]
  \nofiles
 }{}
}
\begin{document}
{
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(0.84\textwidth,0.07cm)
    \includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{logo.eps} 
\end{textblock*}
}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Hi}
HEY
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Material?}
My book                     
        \end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Course Website}
Nothing
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I also tried to include the logo file; but .eps format is not accepted and I could not upload it...

I need to add that, if you want to run it in handout mode, please make the first line comment and uncomment the second line.

Comment: Related: [LaTeX beamer handout mode textpos](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70348/latex-beamer-handout-mode-textpos)

Comment: @cyberSingularity: Thank you. Can you please, somehow, make it an answer then I can accept it?

Comment: @NNik If your question is the same as a previous one, we'll close this as a dupe. Let me know if that's what you feel is appropriate, and I'll do it.

Comment: @JosephWright To the extent that removing the `absolute` option from the `textpos` package doesn't really solve the problem (the logo disappears) it's not clear that the linked question is a pure duplicate.

Comment: @JosephWright: I agree with Alan that although this is the same issue with the same cause (and the OP seems happy with the solution in the linked question), the solutions here can relate to what is actually trying to be achieved (logo in the header) whereas the linked question has undisclosed reasons for wanting to use the `textpos` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `textpos` with the `absolute` option causes different output when using `pgfpages` (it doesn't cause problems with the `handout` option when not using `pgfpages`), even when using `\nofiles`, because the `absolute` position is in terms of the physical page, not the logical page.

To display a logo in the header, one would ideally use a `beamer` (outer) theme designed for this purpose, preferably together with the `\logo` interface that `beamer` provides, instead of employing `textpos`. Unfortunately, I am not aware of any existing themes that have the logo where you want it.

The following solution avoids using `textpos` altogether, and tries to use `beamer`'s `\logo` feature to some extent (and hopefully still has some sensible behaviour regardless of which template you use), but it is still inelegant:

- One cannot just move the logo position in the `sidebar right` template, as the `frametitle` gets placed on top of it. Therefore, we can instead switch off `\insertlogo` in the `sidebar right` template...

  ```
  % prevent the logo from appearing in the usual position on pages
  \addtobeamertemplate{sidebar right}{%
      \let\insertlogo\relax% don't worry, the template is executed in a group!
  }{}
  ```
- ...and put another `\insertlogo` in the `frametitle` template, appropriately positioned:

  ```
  % modify the frametitle template in a generic manner
  % so that within it, \insertframetitle also inserts a right aligned box (apparently of no height/width) containing the logo
  % elsewhere, \insertframetitle behaves as normal and does not include this logo!
  \addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \let\oldinsertframetitle\insertframetitle
  \def\insertframetitle{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\oldinsertframetitle}\vbox to 0pt{\vtop{\vskip-0.6cm\makebox[0pt][r]{\insertlogo}}}}%
  }%
  {}%
  ```

  If you want the horizontal position to be more like as in your original example, add `\hspace{1.5cm}` after `\insertlogo` in the `\def\insertframetitle`.

Note that the positioning method for the logo in the frame title is not great.

I have also placed this in the context of your MWE, which I have also made a few changes to:

1. Used `\titlegraphic` instead of your previous hack for setting the logo on the title page.
2. Used `example-image-a` from the `mwe` package, as I (and others) do not have the logo you were using.
3. Reduced some of the `pgfpages` layout code you were using. Rather than essentially copying the original `2 on 1` definition just to add a border, I just declared a layout that loaded the original definition. Note that it is not identical to your version, however.
4. Tried to improve the `\nofiles` issue, by ensuring that at least 2 proper LaTeX runs occur before invoking `pgfpages` and `\nofiles`. Now the `LastPage` counters in the footers are correct. (Of course, whether or not you experience any issue depends on how many times you compile the file without the `handout` mode.) *This is why my code is so long...*
5. Replaced one of the `\documentclass` lines with a `\PassOptionsToClass` line, as it makes the difference clearer and it is only one line to comment/uncomment instead of two.
6. Removed a few things that were unneeded.
7. Moved the `frametitle` patching to the preamble.

Full code:

```
\PassOptionsToClass{handout}{beamer}% just comment out this line to disable handout mode
\documentclass [11 pt, xcolor=pdftex,x11names,table]{beamer} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{mwe}% for example-image-a (requiring the package helps the package manager)

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Madrid}
    \usecolortheme{orchid}
    \usecolortheme{whale}
}
\title{Hi}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

% use the \logo and \titlegraphic facilities provided by beamer
\logo{\includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{example-image-a}}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-a}}

% prevent the logo from appearing in the usual position on pages
\addtobeamertemplate{sidebar right}{%
    \let\insertlogo\relax% don't worry, the template is executed in a group!
}{}
% modify the frametitle template in a generic manner
% so that within it, \insertframetitle also inserts a right aligned box (apparently of no height/width) containing the logo
% elsewhere, \insertframetitle behaves as normal and does not include this logo!
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
\let\oldinsertframetitle\insertframetitle
\def\insertframetitle{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\oldinsertframetitle}\vbox to 0pt{\vtop{\vskip-0.6cm\makebox[0pt][r]{\insertlogo}}}}%
}%
{}%

\makeatletter

\mode<handout>
{
    % based on [Beamer handout: Problem when creating border around frames](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53606)
    \def\pgfpagesborderstrokeifnotempty{%
        \expandafter\ifvoid\csname pgfpages@box@\the\pgf@cpn\endcsname
        \else
        \expandafter\pgfstroke
        \fi
    }

    % count number of LaTeX runs to attempt to guess if we can activate pgfpages and execute \nofiles
    \newcommand*{\IfRanMoreThan}[1]{\ifnum\value{counttexrunsforpgfpages}>#1\relax\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}%

    % following mostly borrowed from counttexruns.sty
    % can't just use that package directly;
    % have to split because we don't always want to update the counter (breaks latexmk)
    % when editing the file, should also delete \jobname.\counttexrunsforpgfpages@extension to allow recompilation enough times
    \newcounter{counttexrunsforpgfpages}%
    \newwrite\@counttexrunsforpgfpagesfile
    \def\counttexrunsforpgfpages@extension{pgfpages.ctr}%
    \IfFileExists{\jobname.\counttexrunsforpgfpages@extension}{%
      \immediate\openin\@counttexrunsforpgfpagesfile=\jobname.\counttexrunsforpgfpages@extension
      \immediate\read\@counttexrunsforpgfpagesfile to \@counttexrunsforpgfpages
      \immediate\read\@counttexrunsforpgfpagesfile to \@counttexrunsforpgfpages
      \immediate\closein\@counttexrunsforpgfpagesfile
      \setcounter{counttexrunsforpgfpages}{\@counttexrunsforpgfpages}
    }{}%
    \stepcounter{counttexrunsforpgfpages}%

    \IfRanMoreThan{2}{%hope file gets compiled enough times without pgfpages being active (only need to ensure the lines \pgfpagesuselayout and \nofiles are in this block, but save time by not loading the packages if not needed in current run)
        \usepackage{pgf}
        \usepackage{pgfpages}
        % extend the default definition of the '2 on 1' layout to add a border to each logical page,
        % without having to copy the whole of the original layout definition
        \pgfpagesdeclarelayout{2 on 1 boxed}%
        {%
            \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}%
            \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{10pt}%change default value for border shrink
        }%
        {%
            \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}{%
                border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\pgfpagesborderstrokeifnotempty,
                resized width=0.85\pgfphysicalwidth,
            }%
            \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}{%
                border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\pgfpagesborderstrokeifnotempty,
                resized width=0.85\pgfphysicalwidth,
            }%
        }%
        \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1 boxed}[letterpaper, border shrink=5mm]
        \nofiles
    }{%
        % save the number of runs to the file! also adjusted from counttexruns.sty
        \immediate\openout\@counttexrunsforpgfpagesfile=\jobname.\counttexrunsforpgfpages@extension
        \catcode`\%=11\relax
        \immediate\write\@counttexrunsforpgfpagesfile{%% This file
          '\jobname.\counttexrunsforpgfpages@extension' was not really generated by the package counttexruns}
        \catcode`\%=14\relax
        \immediate\write\@counttexrunsforpgfpagesfile{\arabic{counttexrunsforpgfpages}}
        \immediate\closeout\@counttexrunsforpgfpagesfile
    }%
}% end \mode<handout>
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% \titlepage doesn't use \frametitle, so the logo only appears there in the \titlegraphic
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Hi}
    HEY
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Material?}
    My book
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Course Website}
    Nothing
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: First (physical) page of output]

Answer (score 2):

This works: Just remove `absolute` option for `textpos` and re-tune the logo position:

```
%\documentclass [11 pt, xcolor=pdftex,x11names,table]{beamer} 
\documentclass[11 pt, handout,x11names,table]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgf, pgfpages, pgfplots}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[overlay]{textpos}
\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Madrid}
    \usecolortheme{orchid}
    \usecolortheme{whale}
}
\title[]{Hi}
\author {\Large{\emph{Me}}}
\date[\today]{\today \\ $ $ \\
\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image}}
\makeatletter
\def\strokeifnotempty{%
\expandafter\ifvoid\csname pgfpages@box@\the\pgf@cpn\endcsname
\let\@next=\relax
\else
\let\@next=\pgfstroke
\fi
\@next%
}
\makeatother
\mode<handout>
{
  \usepackage{pgf}
  \usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{2 on 1 boxed}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperheight} 
  \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperwidth}
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{10pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=2,%
    physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight,%
    physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}
  {%
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\strokeifnotempty,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=0.85\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{0.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.25\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {%
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\strokeifnotempty,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=0.85\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.75\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
  }
\IfFileExists{\jobname.aux}{
  \pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1 boxed}[letterpaper, border shrink=5mm]
  \nofiles
 }{}
}
\begin{document}
{
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{
\begin{textblock*}{100mm}(0.84\textwidth,-0.9cm)
    \includegraphics[height=0.8cm]{example-image} 
\end{textblock*}
}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Hi}
HEY
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Material?}
My book                     
        \end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Course Website}
Nothing
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your solution works as well :) Thanks